# TCP соединение без подключения устройств к одному wifi

Tags: python, сокет, tcp

Недавно начал знакомиться с библиотекой sockets в питоне. Когда оба устройства подключены к локальному wifi, то всё работает. Но стоит перейти на мобильный интернет или запустить с другого пк, то даже с открытым портом и указанным айпи подключаться не будет. Как можно организовать соединение между двумя устройствами, не подключенными к одной сети? Вот код на всякий:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('192.168.11.311', 12345))
sock.listen(1)

conn, addr = sock.accept()

print ('connected:', addr)

Клиент:
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('192.168.11.311', 12345))

while True:
    
client.send(input().encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Для начала наладить связь между сетями, к которым они подключены, и питон тут уже ни при чём, это делается на уровне роутеров и интернет-провайдеров

Comment: Добавлю для пояснения: Программы здесь не причём.  Проблема в том, что передача из одной сети в другую идёт через Инет. А в иНете нет ваших локальных IP.  И тут есть два решения: либо покупать у провайдера статические IP, либо настраивать в шлюзе(роутере) так называемую таблицу NAT. Тема большая и непростая.